How to solve this equation analytically
when considering the problem of solving how much mass of fuel does a rocket need in order to leave earth, we come across this equation:
$$
v_{\infty}=-\frac{g}{Q}m_c+u\ln(1+\frac{m_c}{m_f})
$$
Where $g,Q,u,m_f$ are known and we want to solve for $m_c$.
Inherently this comes down to solving the equation:
$$
ax+b\ln(1+cx)+d=0
$$
Where $x\in\mathbb{R^{+*}}$ since the amount of fuel is strictly positive, $a,b,d\in\mathbb{R}$ and $c>-1/x$
Does an exact anallytical solution exist? If so, how do we come to find it?

@JeanMarie Should've he said "the earth" if he wanted to use a lowercase "e"?

It can be solved using the Lambert W function: with $t = 1 + c x$, write the equation in the form
$$ \alpha t + \ln(t) + \beta = 0 $$
with $\alpha = a/(bc)$ and $\beta = d/b - a/(bc)$.
Then the solutions are $$t = \exp\left(-\beta - W(\alpha/e^\beta)\right)$$
where $W$ is (a branch of) Lambert W.
